# No display on boot with Radeon HD6620G

Tags: 11.10, radeon

I have an HP laptop with a Radeon HD6620G.  When I try to boot the live CD for 11.10, I just get a black screen.

I know Ubuntu's loading, because I can hear the startup sound.

Any ideas?